# problems with convert some part of string to a int python

Tags: python, string, int

I have a problem converting string to int.
I want to add the length of a string to the start of it (i can only use 2 digits)
and then know the length of the string by using the start of the string(the 2 digits)
if the string length is less then 10 then add a 0 before the length
i tried to do this

```
command = "0"+str(len(command))+command
```

but it doesn't work but i don't know why because

```
command = "04EXIT"
int(command[0:2])
```

will print 4 and

`int("04")` will also print 4 so i don't know why this isn't working

thanks ahead to all the helpers

Comment: Not sure why it does not work for you. I just tried it out with this series of commands. `>>> command = "EXIT"`
`>>> command = "0"+str(len(command))+command`
`>>> command
'04EXIT'`
`>>> int(command[0:2])
4`

Comment: How are you setting the variable `command`?

Answer (score 1):

You are conflating `strings` and `ints`. In Python (and for humans) `4 == 04 == 004 == 0004 == ...`. On the other hand, a string is a sequence of characters. In your case a '0' character followed by a '4' character. That is different than a single character '4'. When you convert '04' to `int` Python says well that is the same thing as 4. Because `4` is a simpler way to represent this integer than `04`, Python displays `4`.

Also you can use Python's format specifiers to get your command:

```
command = 'hi'
command = "%02d" % len(command) + command  # '02hi'
```

or convert to string and use [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill):

```
command = str(len(command)).zfill(2) + command  # '02hi'
```

Comment: first thanks for answering the thing is the command is sending in a socket so doing the %02d% is not so good because tactility i i don't know the command length that why im adding the length at the begging

Comment: and if a "04" is different then 04 why int("04") works ?